# Static sound when wifi stick is connected to the PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, audio

My internet connection is through a USB wifi stick, but every time I connect it to the PC, there's this static sound. It's really annoying, can't enjoy games, films, music, when I'm connected to the internet. Anyone knows how to fix this? I think this is not unlike the sound heard back when people connect their telephones to their computers for the internet connection and when you listen to the phone there's this sound. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never mind folks, it looks like the USB port that I connect my internet stick to should be far from the audio ports. Everything's okay now.

Comment: Please post your solution as an Answer (not just a comment), and then accept your own Answer. That way this question will show up as having been satisfactorily answered. If you read the SuperUser FAQ you'll see that this is not only okay to do, it's encouraged in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Scientific answer: A computer has lots of signals travelling through the wires and circuit board traces which induce currents in the sound circuits of the computer. If the noise is very annoying consider purchasing an outboard sound card that plugs into the USB port. This way the audio is kept digital until it's outside of the PC's case and in a quieter environment.

I remember having a BSR soundcard in the year 1996 and comparing the signal-to-noise ratio of the sound card to a finger-oiled scratched 45 RPM record on a kiddie suitcase record player was like comparing the difference between a rocket at a launch pad and an anechoic chamber.